# MemoryError with django during bulk data insertion

Tags: mysql, django, memory

I have a django app running on a Linux machine. This app uses a MySQL db that contains a list of over 40,000 employers.
I have a django management command that goes through this list of employers, and for each one, downloads and inserts to the database its employees. Some employers have a under a 100 employees, but some have thousands. As such, we are talking about a lot of data.

When I run this command, everything seems to be working fine, until at some point (about an hour in) I get a MemoryError. I can't figure out where I am leaking memory. Here is my code:

```
import urllib3

class API:
    @staticmethod
    def getEmployees(employer):

        employees = []

        url = 'someapiurl'
        http_pool = urllib3.connection_from_url(url)
        req = http_pool.get_url(url)

        #this parsing takes between 0.1 to 5 seconds, depending on the size of the response
        doc = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(req.data)

        nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(MATCHING_ELEMENTS)

        for node in nodes:
            employee = Employee()
            employee.createDataFromNode(node)
            employees.append(employee)

        return employee


class SomeClass:
    #only commit on success - this is to prevent commits from happening every single time save() is called.  

    @transcation.commit_on_success
    @staticmethod
    def createAll():
        #there are over 40,000 employers
        for employer in Employers.objects.all():
            SomeClass.createEmployeesForEmployer(employer)

    @staticmethod
    def createEmployeesForEmployer(employer):
        employees = API.getEmployees(employer)
        for employee in employees:
                employee.save()
```

What could be the problem here? Thank you!

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace?

Comment: Do you have a debug off on your server?

Comment: hi - no, my debug is on. could that be causing this?

Comment: @Aldarund your comment saved my day! Thanks!